# If $E_1, E_2$ are connected and $A_1\subseteq E_1$ and $A_2\subseteq E_2$ then $(E_1\times E_2)-(A_1\times A_2)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $E_1$, $E_2$ connected metric spaces. Let $A_1\subseteq E_1$ and $A_2\subseteq E_2$ proper subsets. Show that the complement of $A_1\times A_2$ $$(E_1\times E_2)-(A_1\times A_2)$$ is connected.

I have tried to perform the test using the result that says if $A, B$ are connected and $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$ then $A\cup B$ is connected.

Note that  $$(E_1\times E_2)-(A_1\times A_2) = \left[E_1\times(E_2-A_2)\right]\cup\left[(E_1-A_1)\times E_2\right]$$ So it suffices to prove that the sets $E_1\times(E_2-A_2)$ and $(E_1-A_1)\times E_2$ are related and non-empty